# Reading gzipped files using read.table()

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I'm getting an error when trying to reload the cross-reference and hprd tables from the [UCSC Table Browser](https://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTables?hgsid=728319257_dOcIkYFF3TaA5sZtJbKHmotvFKkV):

```r
kgxref=read.table("kgXref.txt.gz",sep="\t",as.is=T,comment="",header=T,quote="")
```

```r
hprd=read.table("humanHprdP2P.txt.gz",as.is=T,header=T,comment="")
```

I keep getting the error:

```r
Error in read.table("kgXref.txt.gz", sep = "\t", as.is = T, comment = "", : invalid numeric 'as.is' expression
```

I've checked that my filenames are typed correctly, the working directory is set to the correct folder, and I've tried to load the files both with and without the ".gz" extensions (I have both the zipped and unzipped versions in the wd).

I should probably add that I had this exact code working a few weeks ago. I recently updated my OS (Mac Mojave), R (3.6.0) and RStudio (Version 1.2.1335) last week in order to install a few packages that were not compatible with my older versions. I feel like this may have something to do with it.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing, by using ***as.is = TRUE*** we are trying to avoid columns to become class of factor, and want to keep them as class of character. Plus those files have no headers.

Here are options:

```
# keep strings as character (avoid factors)
kgxref <- read.table("kgXref.txt.gz", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep = "\t")
```

Using *data.table::fread*:

```
# use fread instead, with default settings it reads the file as expected
kgxref <- fread("kgXref.txt.gz")
```

Or even better, using *fread*, we can directly get the table from the link:

```
# fread with a link to zipped data file from UCSC
kgxref <- fread("http://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenpath/hg19/database/kgXref.txt.gz")
humanHprdP2P <- fread("http://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenpath/hg19/database/humanHprdP2P.txt.gz")
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `as.is` parameter is a **vector** according to `read.table` documentation:

> the default behavior of read.table is to convert character variables (which are not converted to logical, numeric or complex) to factors. The variable as.is controls the conversion of columns not otherwise specified by colClasses. Its value is either a **vector of logicals** (values are recycled if necessary), or a **vector of numeric or character indices** which specify which columns should not be converted to factors.
>   Note: to suppress all conversions including those of numeric columns, set colClasses = "character".
>   Note that as.is is specified per column (not per variable) and so includes the column of row names (if any) and any columns to be skipped.

So in order to check if this is the problem I would remove the parameter totally:

```
hprd=read.table("humanHprdP2P.txt.gz",header=T,comment="")
```

Then, if it works, specify a vector with the column indices that should be kept "as is" or booleans, like `c(2,3)`.

I am sorry I cannot be more precise with a minimal working example of this, but hope it helps.